# How to write passed variables using sendkeys

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Brief explanation: trying to use sendkeys to type two variables/keys from the output of a batch file.

I keep getting syntax or out of subscript errors.

Two variables are passed from a batch script, via:

```
cscript //nologo sendKeys.vbs !config! !arguments!
rem Yes, both variables are defined, and delayed expansion in enabled.
```

My attempts to put them in sendkeys doesn't seem to work. I'm not familiar with VBS...

VBScript:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "notepad.exe", 9             ' Start notepad in order to test my failure.
WScript.Sleep 500                         ' Give notepad time to load

WshShell.SendKeys & WshShell.Arguments(0) ' write passed !config! variable
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"                 ' tab key
WshShell.SendKeys & WshShell.Arguments(1) ' write passed !arguments! variable
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"               ' enter key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Arguments belong to the WScript object, not the Shell. `&` is the concatenation operator, it makes no sense between a method name and the first/only argument. So use

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "notepad.exe", 9             ' Start notepad in order to test my failure.
WScript.Sleep 500                         ' Give notepad time to load

WshShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments(0)    ' write passed !config! variable
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"                 ' tab key
WshShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments(1)    ' write passed !arguments! variable
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"               ' enter key
```

or - better - think about a way to solve your real world problem without SendKeys.

Comment: The application i'm spamming input into doesn't support passing variables to it, and anything but these two languages and I'm lost. Thanks for the answer, sorry it was so simple.